# Downlgrading linux kernel version in openwrt throws build error

Tags: linux, build, linux-kernel, openwrt

I was trying to downgrade the linux kernel version from 4.4.14(trunk) to 3.18.44.
I made the necessary makefile changes for my target linux system which is ipq806x.
But while building I am getting patch failed error. The build log snippet is given below. Has anyone come across such kind of an error. Please share your comments.

```
pplying patch platform/301-ARM-qcom-add-Netgear-Nighthawk-X4-R7500-device-tree.patch
patching file arch/arm/boot/dts/Makefile
The next patch would create the file arch/arm/boot/dts/qcom-ipq8064-r7500.dts,
which already exists!  Applying it anyway.
patching file arch/arm/boot/dts/qcom-ipq8064-r7500.dts
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- rejects in file arch/arm/boot/dts/qcom-ipq8064-r7500.dts
Patch platform/301-ARM-qcom-add-Netgear-Nighthawk-X4-R7500-device-tree.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
Makefile:26: recipe for target '/home/guru/punya/trunkpull_24112017/openwrt/build_dir/target-arm_cortex-a9+neon-vfpv4_musl-1.1.16_eabi/linux-ipq806x/linux-3.18.44/.quilt_checked' failed
make[4]: *** [/home/guru/punya/trunkpull_24112017/openwrt/build_dir/target-arm_cortex-a9+neon-vfpv4_musl-1.1.16_eabi/linux-ipq806x/linux-3.18.44/.quilt_checked] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/guru/punya/trunkpull_24112017/openwrt/target/linux/ipq806x'
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make[3]: *** [compile] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/guru/punya/trunkpull_24112017/openwrt/target/linux'
target/Makefile:21: recipe for target 'target/linux/compile' failed
make[2]: *** [target/linux/compile] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/guru/punya/trunkpull_24112017/openwrt'
target/Makefile:16: recipe for target '/home/guru/punya/trunkpull_24112017/openwrt/staging_dir/target-arm_cortex-a9+neon-vfpv4_musl-1.1.16_eabi/stamp/.target_compile' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/guru/punya/trunkpull_24112017/openwrt/staging_dir/target-arm_cortex-a9+neon-vfpv4_musl-1.1.16_eabi/stamp/.target_compile] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/guru/punya/trunkpull_24112017/openwrt'
/home/guru/punya/trunkpull_24112017/openwrt/include/toplevel.mk:192: recipe for target 'world' failed
make: *** [world] Error 2
```

Comment: Is this question related with C?

Comment: Sorry no, it is a build related issue

Answer (score 0):

From the logs its clear the compilation failed because of patching of dts failed.
If the failed patch file is not required then try the compilation after removing it.